Converting XML Records to JSON Using XSLT Transformation - Issue with Number Formatting
I'm working on a project where I fetch data from a database using a stored procedure. The data is returned in XML format like this:
<record>
      <field name="ID">8f7e-25fbcce2cdc7</field>
      <field name="TRANSACTIONSTATUS">202</field>
      <field name="TRANSAMT">1.90</field>
      <field name="SNDNAME">MR. Jade</field>
      <field name="RECVNAME">MR. Lucas</field>
      <field name="SNDACCTNUMBER">8224002623</field>
      <field name="RECVACCTNUMBER">5666666</field>
</record>

I'm using XSLT transformation in WSO2 EI to convert this XML into JSON format. Here's the XSLT code I'm using:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry key="CTDetailsById_Formatter_LE" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:variable name="ctDetails" select="//*[local-name()='table']/*[local-name()='record']"/>
            <jsonElement>
                <xsl:element name="transactionId">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$ctDetails/*[local-name()='field'][@name='ID']"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="status">
                    <xsl:variable name="TrnStatus" select="$ctDetails/*[local-name()='field'][@name='TRANSACTIONSTATUS']"/>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$TrnStatus='202'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="'pending'"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$TrnStatus='204'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="'initiated'"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$TrnStatus='203'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="'completed'"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise/>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="credittrasfer">
                    <xsl:element name="amount">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$ctDetails/*[local-name()='field'][@name='TRANSAMT']"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="sendername">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$ctDetails/*[local-name()='field'][@name='SNDNAME']"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="receivername">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$ctDetails/*[local-name()='field'][@name='RECVNAME']"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="senderacctnumber">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$ctDetails/*[local-name()='field'][@name='SNDACCTNUMBER']"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="receiveracctnumber">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$ctDetails/*[local-name()='field'][@name='RECVACCTNUMBER']"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </jsonElement>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:transform>
</localEntry>

The problem I'm facing is with the formatting of numbers in the JSON output. For example, the SNDACCTNUMBER and RECVACCTNUMBER field should be a string in the JSON output, but it's coming out as a number without quotes. Here's the JSON output I'm getting:
{
    "transactionId": "M20240425101010101MTBOTS06651000849",
    "status": "pending",
    "credittrasfer": {
        "amount": 1.90,
        "sendername": "MR. Jade",
        "receivername": "MR. Lucas",
        "senderacctnumber": 8224002623, // This should be "8224002623"
        "receiveracctnumber": 5666666 // This should be "5666666"
    }
}

I've tried different approaches in the XSLT code to format the numbers as strings in the JSON output, but I haven't been successful so far. Can someone guide me on how to ensure that specific fields like SNDACCTNUMBER and RECVACCTNUMBER are formatted as strings in the JSON output using XSLT?

Your XSLT code does not produce JSON. It produces an XML result that another part of your processing chain converts to JSON. There is no indication in the XML result regarding the type of an element. Apparently the converter makes an assumption based either on the contents (e.g. digits only) or the element name.

This behavior is acceptable in the wso2 synapse engine. when the XML to json transformation is happening, there is no information to decide whether the primitive data type is number or string. hence by default, it treate numbers as numbers. if you need to change the json message as you need, let's use JSON Transform Mediator[1] after converting the message to json. Please note that this mediator is available with EI 660 onwards.
[1] https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/json-Transform-Mediator/

Thanks for the JSON Transform Mediator suggestion in WSO2 MI.
Encountered an issue: the amount field is not retaining with two decimal places, leading to JsonNull error when empty fields exist.
JSON Response:
{     "transactionId": "M20240425101010101MTBOTS06651000849",     "status": "pending",     "credittrasfer": {         "amount": 1.9,         "sendername": "MR. Jade",         "receivername": "MR. Lucas",         "senderacctnumber": "8224002623",          "receiveracctnumber": "5666666"      } } 
Error: JsonNull java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNull

Despite being standard behavior when transforming from XML to json, and axis2 messageformater has no information to decide whether the primitive data type is a number or a string and is there by using the standard.
There is a way to work around it. It is not very well known but possible to create json with a xslt. by useof
<xsl:output method=“text” indent=“yes” media-type=“application/json” encoding=“UTF-8”/>
when using xslt or the payload factory to create json you can force the quotes by just putting them arround the xpath value.
Here by the complete xslt i used in your case
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl soapenv ">  

<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" media-type="application/json" encoding="UTF-8"/> 
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/record">{
"transactionId": "<xsl:value-of select="./field[@name='ID']"/>,",
"status":
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="./field[@name='TRANSACTIONSTATUS']='202'">
        <xsl:text>"pending"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="./field[@name='TRANSACTIONSTATUS']='204'">
        <xsl:text>"initiated"</xsl:text>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="./field[@name='TRANSACTIONSTATUS']='203'">
        <xsl:text>"completed"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>""</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>,
"credittransfer": {
    "amount": <xsl:value-of select="./field[@name='TRANSAMT']"/>,
    "sendername": "<xsl:value-of select="./field[@name='SNDNAME']"/>",
    "receivername": "<xsl:value-of select="./field[@name='RECVNAME']"/>",
    "senderacctnumber": "<xsl:value-of select="./field[@name='SNDACCTNUMBER']"/>",
    "receiveracctnumber": "<xsl:value-of select="./field[@name='RECVACCTNUMBER']"/>"
}
}</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>

also the demo proxy used:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><proxy name="DemoJsonXsltProxy"
xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" transports="http https" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
<target>
    <inSequence>
        <log level="full">
            <property name="#### START" value="Enter DemoJsonXslt Service"/>
        </log>

        <xslt key="gov:nl/boontjesit/adapters/wso2-mi-jsonxslt-service/v1_0/xslt/DemoJsonXslt_v1_0.xslt" />
        <!-- Make sure that the json from the xslt is actually recognized as json -->
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>$1</format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/*"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
        <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>

        <log level="full">
            <property name="#### END" value="Complete DemoJsonXslt Service"/>
        </log>
        <respond/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
</target></proxy>

Result:    Result of DemoJsonXsltProxy
Other solution is using the payload factory only the Choose you do in the xslt should be performed before using the payloadFactory.
     <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format> "credittransfer": {
                    "amount": $1,
                    "sendername": $2,
                    "receivername":$3,
                    "senderacctnumber": "$4",
                    "receiveracctnumber": "$5"
                } 
            </format>
            <args>
                <arg expression="//record/field[@name='TRANSAMT']" evaluator="xml" />
                <arg expression="//record/field[@name='SNDNAME']" evaluator="xml" />
                <arg expression="//record/field[@name='RECVNAME']" evaluator="xml" />
                <arg expression="//record/field[@name='SNDACCTNUMBER']" evaluator="xml" />
                <arg expression="//record/field[@name='RECVACCTNUMBER']" evaluator="xml" />
            </args>
     </payloadFactory>

Note: I changed "credittrasfer" to "credittransfer" because thinking it was a typo?

@oshada-eranga was this solution sufficient for your problem?
